# React routing cannot read pathname property on navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have recently started developing frontend apps with React and I come from a little programming experience with react-native.
To improve my knowledge on react I studied both the official documentation and took courses on udemy.
So I'm building a small test app in which to use react routing (following what we saw in the udemy course).
However, I have the following error related to routing (I attach the error screen)

[image]

I have searched here on the stack that online for possible solutions, such as downgrading react-router-dom, or modifying the history declaration, but unfortunately I still get this error and I can't understand what it comes from.
Do you have any suggestions or advice?

**My app configuration:**

- package.json

```
  "name": "app1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

- routes.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Component1 from './functional/component1';
import Component2 from './functional/component2';
import Component3 from './functional/component3';

//import container home-page
import Container1 from './containers/container1';
import Header from './containers/header';
import history from './utils/history';

//react router import
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';

class Routes extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Router history={history.location} navigator={history} >
               <div>
                  <Header />
                  <Route path="/" component={Container1} />
                  <Route path="/component1" component={Component1} />
                  <Route path="/component2" component={Component2} />
                  <Route path="/component3" component={Component3} />
               </div>
            </Router>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default Routes;
```

-history.js

```
var createHistory = require('history').createBrowserHistory;
export default createHistory();
```

Comment: You're supposed to use BrowserRouter (use `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router';` instead), also there's no need for the history package, react-router manages its own history. My recommendation in general would be to use the official tutorial, not some possibly outdated course elsewhere. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

Comment: @ChrisG thank's now i've more clear the behavior of react navigation, i will try to migrate from the course navigation to react-6 navigation like the official docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The low-level `Router` takes a few different props than it did in v5.

[Router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#router)

> ```
> declare function Router(
>   props: RouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   location: Partial<Location> | string; // <-- required
>   navigationType?: NavigationType;
>   navigator: Navigator;                 // <-- required
>   static?: boolean;
> }
> ```

[Router source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L251-L327)

```
export function Router({
  basename: basenameProp = "/",
  children = null,
  location: locationProp, // <-- undefined location
  navigationType = NavigationType.Pop,
  navigator,
  static: staticProp = false,
}: RouterProps): React.ReactElement | null {
  ...

  let {
    pathname = "/", // <-- cannot read "pathname" of undefined!
    search = "",
    hash = "",
    state = null,
    key = "default",
  } = locationProp;

  ...

  if (location == null) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContext.Provider value={navigationContext}>
      <LocationContext.Provider
        children={children}
        value={{ location, navigationType }}
      />
    </NavigationContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

You are incorrectly using a `history` prop instead of the `location` prop, and this is why `location` is undefined in the component and unable to read a `pathname`.

Additionally, in `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` components necessarily need to be wrapped in the `Routes` component in order for route path matching and rendering to work.

## Solution

Pass the correct required props and wrap the `Route` components in `Routes` component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Component1 from './functional/component1';
import Component2 from './functional/component2';
import Component3 from './functional/component3';

//import container home-page
import Container1 from './containers/container1';
import Header from './containers/header';
import history from './utils/history';

//react router import
import { Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router';

class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router location={history.location} navigator={history} >
          <div>
            <Header />
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" component={Container1} />
              <Route path="/component1" component={Component1} />
              <Route path="/component2" component={Component2} />
              <Route path="/component3" component={Component3} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `react router v6` and in `v6` you have to wrap all of your `route's` in `<Routes>...</Routes>` tag.

```
//react router import
import { Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router'; // Make sure to import ----Routes----

class Routes extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Router history={history.location} navigator={history} >
               <div>
                  <Header />
                  <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" component={Container1} />
                    <Route path="/component1" component={Component1} />
                    <Route path="/component2" component={Component2} />
                    <Route path="/component3" component={Component3} />
                  </Routes>
               </div>
            </Router>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default Routes;
```

And you can't add anything between `<Routes>...</Routes>` except `<Route />`.

Comment: That's just one of several issues though.

Comment: I've modified like your code, and renamig the class from `Routes` to `Routers` otherwise i've a naming conflict, but i've the same problem